# a-z list,  categories and sub categories in loop

Tags: categories, loop

I'd like to list my categories in a loop from a-z, the code i currently have just keeps repeating over and over im not sure what the problem is but the format should look something like.

- Parent Category

  - Child Category
  - Child Category
  - Child Category
  - Child Category

**My code:**

```
<?php 
$args = array( 'orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC' );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<p><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">'.$category->category_nicename.'</a></p>';
    echo '<p class="cat-child"><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">'.$category->child.'</a></p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you querying for posts if you want categories?

Comment: to get the categories to show, they wont show unless they have post inside them correct?

Comment: I'm not sure i follow... do you need a list of posts or categories, or both?

Comment: just categories, im sorry if my code is confusing.

Comment: [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) would probably be more suitable for your use.

Comment: I updated my code you gave a good suggestion but how do i make it to where the 1st row is displaying only the parent title and the 2nd row is the child titles it seems to be displaying all of them

Comment: I'm still struggling to follow, based on the example format you've shown, Gavin's answer should address your needs, if not please clarify more.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to list the categories in a tree structure, in alphabetical order, showing ALL categories (even empty ones)? If so, try this:

```
<?php
    $args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false);
    $categories = wp_list_categories($args);
?>
```

Reference: [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//get only parents
$args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC','parent' => 0);
$Parent_categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($Parent_categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">'.$category->category_nicename.'</a><br/>';
    //get all children of this category
    $args = array('orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC','parent' => $category->term_id);
    $Child_categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($Child_categories as $c){
        echo '<span class="cat-child"><a href="'.get_category_link( $c->term_id ).'">'.$c->category_nicename.'</a></span>  ';
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get & list all categories, with sub-categories, like a "tree"! 
see solution: 
**[How to sort list of custom posts to get view like a tree of posts under categories and their children's categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80193/how-to-sort-list-of-custom-posts-to-get-view-like-a-tree-of-posts-under-categori)**