# How to sort list of custom posts to get view like a tree of posts under categories and their children's categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, page-template

I'm new here and my english isn't perfect so I'm sorry for this :) I'm here because I'm workin on site with post list sorted by category and I have problem with sort out my posts in categories and children categories under them. Now everything is messed up. I would like to sort my custom  posts like that:

CATEGORY 1

- CHILD CATEGORY 1

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post
- CHILD CATEGORY2

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post

CATEGORY 2

- CHILD CATEGORY3

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post

CATEGORY 3

- Post
- Post
- CHILD CATEGORY4

  - Post
  - Post
  - Post

Is it possible with this code:

```
<?php
$querystr = "SELECT terms.* FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy tax LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms terms ON       tax.term_id = terms.term_id WHERE tax.taxonomy = 'MY_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY'";

$categories = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

foreach( $categories as $category ): 
echo '<div class="category-header"><h3>'.$category->name.'</h3>';  
echo '<p class="category-description">'.strip_tags(term_description($category->term_id,'MY_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY')).'</p></div>';  

$posts = get_posts( array( 'MY_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY' => $category->name, 'post_type' => 'MY_CUSTOM_POST' ) );  
foreach($posts as $post) :  
setup_postdata($post);  

 the_title();   

endforeach;

endforeach;
?>
```

I will be grateful for all help, thank You!!

Comment: Please add what this is about? Plugin? Theme? And where have you added the code? Please also try to use English replacements in your questions so people can easier imagine what it is about. THanks.

Answer (score 1):

ok, this is my working solution:

```
<?php

$args=array(
'post_type'                => 'biblioteka',
'child_of'                 => 0,
'parent'                   => '',
'orderby'                  => 'name',
'order'                    => 'ASC',
'hide_empty'               => 1,
'hierarchical'             => 1,
'exclude'                  => '',
'include'                  => '',
'number'                   => '',
'taxonomy'                 => 'kategoria-pozycji',
'pad_counts'               => false
);

$categories=get_categories($args);

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

if ( $category->parent > 0 ) {
continue;   
}

echo '<h1 style="font-weight:bold">' . $category->name . '</h1>';

$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
          FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->terms
          WHERE term_id = (" . $category->cat_ID . ")
          AND term_taxonomy_id = (" . $category->term_taxonomy_id . ")
          AND ID = object_id
          AND post_type = 'biblioteka'
          AND post_status = 'publish'
          ORDER BY post_date DESC";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);  

        echo '<li>'; the_title();   echo '</li>';

        }
echo '</ul>';

$categories2 = get_terms('kategoria-pozycji',array('parent' => $category->term_id , 'hide_empty'=> '0' ));

foreach ( $categories2 as $category ) {

echo '<h2>' . $category->name . '</h2>';

$posts = get_posts( array( 'kategoria-pozycji' => $category->name, 'post_type' => 'biblioteka' ) );  

echo '<ul>';
foreach($posts as $post) { 
    setup_postdata($post);  

        echo '<li>'; the_title();   echo '</li>';

        }
echo '</ul>';

}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**My best solution!** (works for any taxonomies,including "category")

```
$your_taxonomy='category';

function my_Categ_tree($TermName='', $termID, $separator='', $parent_shown=true ){
    $args = 'hierarchical=1&taxonomy='.$TermName.'&hide_empty=0&orderby=id&parent=';
            if ($parent_shown) {$term=get_term($termID , $TermName); $output=$separator.$term->name.'('.$term->term_id.')<br/>'; $parent_shown=false;}
    $separator .= '-';  
    $terms = get_terms($TermName, $args . $termID);
    if(count($terms)>0){
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            //$selected = ($cat->term_id=="22") ? " selected": "";
            //$output .=  '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'" '.$selected .'>'.$separator.$category->cat_name.'</option>';
            $output .=  $separator.$term->name.'('.$term->term_id.')<br/>';
            $output .=  my_Categ_tree($TermName, $term->term_id, $separator, $parent_shown);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**Then you can output:**
1) target category(taxonomy) tree, using specific ID

```
echo my_Categ_tree($your_taxonomy, 0 );
```

2) All categories/taxonomies

```
foreach (get_terms($your_taxonomy, array('hide_empty'=>0, 'parent'=>0)) as $each) {
    echo my_Categ_tree($each->taxonomy,$each->term_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I played a little and this is what I came up with, I tested and it works just like your given example:

```
<ul>
<?php

// get initial categories
$categories = get_categories();

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

// we don't want child categories now, and since get_categories does not support 'depth' parameter, we use ->parent check
if ( $category->parent > 0 ) {
    continue;   
}

$i = 0;
echo '<li>' . $category->cat_name . '</li>';

$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'category' => $category->term_id
    )
);

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    // let's make sure that the post is not also in any of child categories, if it is, skip it ( we don't want to display it twice )
    $child_categories = get_term_children( $category->term_id, 'category' );

    if ( $child_categories && in_category( $child_categories, $post->ID ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    echo 0 === $i ? '<ul>' : '';
    echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';
    $i++;

}

// now, after we listed all the posts, we query for child categories
$categories2 = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent' => $category->term_id
    )
);

foreach ( $categories2 as $category ) {

    $j = 0;
    echo '<li>' . $category->cat_name . '</li>';
    $posts2 = get_posts(
        array(
            'category' => $category->term_id
        )
    );

    foreach ( $posts2 as $post ) {

        echo 0 === $j ? '<ul>' : '';
        echo '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';
        $j++;
    }

    echo null === $posts2 ? '' : '</ul>';

}

echo null === $posts ? '' : '</ul>';

}

?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I solved the problems as you experience

```
            //Define Some require
            define(TAX_TYPE, 'category'); //you can also replace your custom taxonomy in category
            $terms = get_terms(TAX_TYPE); 
            define(WP_HOME, 'http://yourdomain.com');


        ?>
        <div class="menu-tours-container">
            <ul id="menu-tours" class="menu">
                <?php 
                    foreach( $terms as $tax_term ) : 

                    $permalink = WP_HOME . '/' . TAX_TYPE . '/' . $tax_term->slug;

                    // getting posts from each tour type
                    $args=array(
                        'post_type'     => 'tour',
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'order_by'      => 'post_title',
                        'order'         => 'ASC',
                        'tour-type'    => $tax_term->slug
                    );
                    $posts = get_posts($args);

                ?>                        
                    <li>
                        <div class="block-title">
                            <h4><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="check">
                            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul> <!--#menu-tours-->

        </div>
```